# Is learning from an unknown guitar teacher better than just learning on my own?

Tags: guitar, classical-guitar, self-learning, lessons, teachers

I've bought a classic guitar two months ago and ever since I'm just playing that without teacher by reading tabletures online. It's very fun and I really like that.

But I think it's now the time (maybe it's late) to go to a teacher.

But the problem is I don't know any good teacher near my place. Some of my friends have some good teachers but there are too far from my home and my workplace and I can't learn from them.

There is a musical institute next to my home but I don't know if its teachers are good or not. Is it a good idea to go there? How can I know if they're good or not?

Comment: It's very subjective. One teacher may be great for one student, but not that good with another. The personality of each comes into play, for starters. If they teach at an institute, one would think they ought to be good, but there are many criteria involved. And some may or may not suit you. First hand experience is probably the answer.

Comment: @Tim I've edited my question and I've given some extra information about institute but I don't know if they have any good guitar teacher or not yet.

Comment: Theoretically, this institute will have some sort of standards for its teachers rather than hiring complete "unknowns".

Comment: I feel like your question should be more along the lines of: how do I recognize a good teacher or a bad one? And then perhaps that question would become a duplicate of this one: http://music.stackexchange.com/q/2556/15535

Comment: or this link that talks about how to be a good guitar teacher: http://music.stackexchange.com/a/39568/15535

Comment: @ceyed Have you played any other instruments or have any knowledge of music theory?

Comment: You know what is really fun. Learning standard notation and sight reading music with all the indications of both rhythm and pitch. Sure it takes a little while to learn to read standard notation but it so worth it

Comment: @Caleb No, I haven't.

Answer (score 5):

The question should not be "is this teacher known?" The question should be "Is this teacher effective?"  Plenty of "unknown" teachers are quite capable of helping you make faster progress than you could make on your own.

Needless to say, you probably *are* better off learning on your own than learning from a *bad* teacher. Unfortunately there are a few of them out there, and you may not know how to recognize them at this stage.

amalgamate in a comment to your original post on how to identify a good teacher and you might find it helpful to read it if you haven't already. The answers should provide a good starting point in identifying a good teacher:  [Becoming a good guitar teacher](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2556/15535) .  You could also try to investigate that institute that is nearby by searching for reviews on line or talking to students who go there.  Don't forget to ask your guitar-player friends' opinions on any teachers that you try if you're unsure about them.

Also, it's never "too late."  Good luck.

Comment: About being late I'm not sure. I'm 19 and I don't have time like an 10 years old boy. I hardly have 30 minutes every night to play my guitar.

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations on your decision to learn to play guitar.  The guitar is a versatile instrument capable of providing musical accompaniment in almost any style of music imaginable.  Playing the guitar will provide untold hours of enjoyment for a lifetime.  But as you have probably figured out by now, it's not exactly the most intuitive and easy instrument to learn.

So I wholeheartedly believe you would benefit tremendously by taking some lessons (even if for only a short while) from the **RIGHT teacher**.

A teacher can analyze your technique and help you become more efficient and proficient - correcting mistakes and bad technique before they become too deeply ingrained.  A good teacher can quickly determine your weaknesses and strengths and a really good teacher will take that information and create a custom learning platform tailored just for you individually - that will build on your strengths and improve on your weaknesses.

But the right teacher for you may not be the right teacher for someone else and vice versa.  The "right" teacher for you will depend to a great extent on what your personal goals are.

Do you want to play primarily for your own enjoyment and possible entertain a few friends?  Or do you aspire to play on a professional level someday?  Do you want to learn classical style using mostly fingerpicking? Or do you want to learn to strum chords and play more of a folk style?  Do you want to learn to play lead guitar - or play rhythm?  **These are some of the questions you must ask yourself before interviewing teachers.**

Keep in mind that the teacher's approach to teaching will vary from teacher to teacher.  Some may prefer to start you out learning theory and learning to sight read and play individual notes from a music staff using standard music notation.  Then you will spend a great deal of instruction time learning about key signatures, rests, time signatures, quarter notes, half notes, ties etcs.  Other's may teach using guitar tablature.  Then you will spend less time learning to read standard music notation, but may need more hands on help with timing, rhythm, and so forth.

Some teacher's approach may be to take it slow, teaching you a solid foundation of the basics, before getting into playing songs.  Other's may choose to teach the basics by teaching songs you like that incorporate the techniques you need to learn to play those songs.

I recommend talking to several different teachers and ask them what their personal teaching philosophy is.  In my opinion, a good teacher would also ask you some questions about what style music you ultimately wish to learn to play and what your specific goals are.  I personally would prefer a teacher who will customize my lessons based on my current abilities and ultimate goals, rather than teaching from a pre-published standard "one size fits all" lesson book.

Be sure the teacher you select does not require you to pay for a bunch of lessons in advance with no opportunity to cancel.  You want to be able to try the teacher out to be sure there is a good fit between their teaching style and your goals and learning style.  If there is not a good fit, don't hesitate to say "this isn't working for me and I want to find a new teacher".

You mentioned that some of your friends have some good teachers.  Ask your friends what they like and dislike about their teachers and how they teach.  Also, ask your friend's teachers if they know any teachers in your area they might refer you to.

Good luck in your quest to find the right teacher.  Don't get too discouraged if your first choice does not seem to be a good fit.  Try another one who might be more in tune with your goals.

Playing the guitar will provide you with a lifetime of enjoyment and opportunities to continually improve your skills.  Enjoy the journey.

Answer (score 1):

I really think it would be a good move to find a teacher being that you don't have much experience in the realm of music. I read your comment saying that you do not have much time to practice. In this case I would strongly recommend some kind of online learning. There are quite a few websites out there. Personally I have used [JamPlay](http://www.jamplay.com/) and it's done wonders to my playing. It's great because you don't have to invest a lot of time or money (it's relatively cheap). And you can dive into any style you want right away.

Also, don't be afraid looking into music theory. I know that lots of people find this subject very intimidating, but it really opens up your eyes to look at music from a different perspective. Of course music came first and then came the theory so don't get to focused on theory or you'll get lost and bored of music.

Another area that has helped my musicianship tremendously is ear training. This area is closely related to music theory so don't feel bummed out if you don't understand a certain concept. I frequently use [this site.](http://www.musictheory.net/)

I know that there will be many set-backs in your journey to master the guitar. But don't let this keep you from advancing. If there is a certain riff that you just can't pull off or theoretical concept that just does not make any sense to you whatsoever, move on. Eventually you will be able to come back to these areas and fully understand them. Sometimes you just might even need to take a break completely and come back in a week or so (don't do this too often).

Finally the main thing is to enjoy learning the guitar. If you're not you might want to consider if you really want to learn this instrument. If you get frustrated put the guitar down and go for a walk. Learning should never be stressful.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Find a teacher to show you the fundamentals of musical technique and performance. Practice the fundamentals. A teacher will instruct you in the right and wrong ways in your musical approach. Do not make excuses why you cannot practice. If you want to learn how to play music you must practise. There are no short cuts. DO NOT rely on tablature. Tablature is inaccurate at best. Learning from Internet resources is fine...but have someone in your musical life to guide you. The fact that your teacher is unknown means nothing. After a couple lessons the teacher will no longer be unknown. Keep things simple and enjoy. Be patient in your musical journey. RESPECT the music. It is defenseless. It is in your care for just a moment...do not treat it unkindly and you will be rewarded with the ability to be creative.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I might add to the conversation by saying, yes, the earlier comments are correct - there are some bad teachers out there.

But the thing is, if you are overly hesitant and never give lessons a shot, then you'll never find a good teacher - or a bad teacher or any kind of teacher for that matter. You need to put yourself out there and experience some good and bad if you want to gain musical maturity - you'd be surprised what or who you'll find. Don't stress out about the perfect teacher. That's not to say don't be critical of any teacher you find, but don't let indecision stop you from ever going to a teacher.

And the references given to you thus far will help you be critical of a teacher, after you give one a shot.